# php file for generating code128 not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried running from libraries and was printing incorrectly the bars, but all the problem was in the script that for some reason conflicts with CI... I guess in the future I have to adapt the code to CI.

```
<?php

function bar128($text) { // Part 1, make list of widths
 $char128asc=' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'; 
$char128wid = array(
 '212222','222122','222221','121223','121322','131222','122213','122312','132212','221213', // 0-9 
 '221312','231212','112232','122132','122231','113222','123122','123221','223211','221132', // 10-19 
 '221231','213212','223112','312131','311222','321122','321221','312212','322112','322211', // 20-29 
 '212123','212321','232121','111323','131123','131321','112313','132113','132311','211313', // 30-39 
 '231113','231311','112133','112331','132131','113123','113321','133121','313121','211331', // 40-49 
 '231131','213113','213311','213131','311123','311321','331121','312113','312311','332111', // 50-59 
 '314111','221411','431111','111224','111422','121124','121421','141122','141221','112214', // 60-69 
 '112412','122114','122411','142112','142211','241211','221114','413111','241112','134111', // 70-79 
 '111242','121142','121241','114212','124112','124211','411212','421112','421211','212141', // 80-89 
 '214121','412121','111143','111341','131141','114113','114311','411113','411311','113141', // 90-99
 '114131','311141','411131','211412','211214','211232','23311120' ); // 100-106
 $w = $char128wid[$sum = 104]; // START symbol
 $onChar=1;
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($text);$x++) // GO THRU TEXT GET LETTERS
 if (!( ($pos = strpos($char128asc,$text[$x])) === false )){ // SKIP NOT FOUND CHARS
 $w.= $char128wid[$pos];
 $sum += $onChar++ * $pos;
 } 
 $w.= $char128wid[ $sum % 103 ].$char128wid[106]; //Check Code, then END
 //Part 2, Write rows
 $html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>"; 
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2) // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
 $html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div></td>"; 
 return "$html<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=1.5>$text</td></tr></table>"; 
}

//include 'barcode128.php';
$product    = $_POST['product'];
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$rate       = $_POST['rate'];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['print_qty']; $i++) {
    echo "<p class='inline'><span ><b>$product</b></span>" . bar128(stripcslashes($_POST['product_id'])) . "<span ><b>Precio: " . $rate . " </b><span></p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
}

?>
```

First, I'm pretty noob on Codeigniter.

I found this php code to generate code128 which I need to print multiple labels from a DB and then send to a Zebra printer.

On pure php it works great, but when integrated to codeigniter using libraries the bars are not printing. Everything is printing except the bars.

On the code in comments you can see all my attempts.

First I tried in the same view "include" "require_once", but then I found that doesn't work on CI or something like that, so I created a new library:

```
//////The lib//////

<?php

global $char128asc,$char128charWidth;
$char128asc=' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'; 
$char128wid = array(
 '212222','222122','222221','121223','121322','131222','122213','122312','132212','221213', // 0-9 
 '221312','231212','112232','122132','122231','113222','123122','123221','223211','221132', // 10-19 
 '221231','213212','223112','312131','311222','321122','321221','312212','322112','322211', // 20-29 
 '212123','212321','232121','111323','131123','131321','112313','132113','132311','211313', // 30-39 
 '231113','231311','112133','112331','132131','113123','113321','133121','313121','211331', // 40-49 
 '231131','213113','213311','213131','311123','311321','331121','312113','312311','332111', // 50-59 
 '314111','221411','431111','111224','111422','121124','121421','141122','141221','112214', // 60-69 
 '112412','122114','122411','142112','142211','241211','221114','413111','241112','134111', // 70-79 
 '111242','121142','121241','114212','124112','124211','411212','421112','421211','212141', // 80-89 
 '214121','412121','111143','111341','131141','114113','114311','411113','411311','113141', // 90-99
 '114131','311141','411131','211412','211214','211232','23311120' ); // 100-106




class Bar128 
{

    function __construct()
    {



function Barra128($cod) { // Part 1, make list of widths
 global $char128asc,$char128wid; 
 $w = $char128wid[$sum = 104]; // START symbol
 $onChar=1;
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($cod);$x++) // GO THRU TEXT GET LETTERS
 if (!( ($pos = strpos($char128asc,$cod[$x])) === false )){ // SKIP NOT FOUND CHARS
 $w.= $char128wid[$pos];
 $sum += $onChar++ * $pos;
 } 
 $w.= $char128wid[ $sum % 103 ].$char128wid[106]; //Check Code, then END
 //Part 2, Write rows
 $html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>"; 
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2) // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
 $html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div></td>"; 
 return "$html<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=1.5>$cod</td></tr></table>"; 
}
}

?>
```

```
//////////// CONTROLLER ///////////

    public function Barcodegenerator()
    {

        //load library
        $this->load->library('Myzend');
        //$this->zend->load('Zend/barcode128');
        //require ('barcode128.php');
        //$this->load->helper('barcode128');
        //require_once APPPATH. 'barcode128.php';
        //require 'barcode128.php';
        //include APPPATH. 'barcode128.php';
        //include('assets/barcode128.php');
        $this->load->view('barcode',$data);

    }
```

```
////////////////// My Lib //////////


<?php if( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require('Zend/barcode128.php');

class MyZend extends Bar128 {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $CI =& get_instance();
}

}
```

```
/////////////// THE VIEW //////////


<?php

//define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
//require_once(__ROOT__.'/barcode128.php');
//require_once('../barcode/barcode128.php');
//require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/barcode128.php';
//require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/barcode/barcode128.php');
//echo include(base_url().'../barcode/barcode128.php');
//require_once 'barcode128.php';
//require 'barcode128.php';
//include 'barcode128.php';
$product    = $_POST['product'];
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$rate       = $_POST['rate'];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['print_qty']; $i++) {
    echo "<p class='inline'><span ><b>$product</b></span>" . Barra128(stripcslashes($_POST['product_id'])) . "<span ><b>Precio: " . $rate . " </b><span></p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
}

?>
```

Comment: In your library, the `require` statement should be relative to the main Codeigniter `index.php` file. As a bonus, I'd suggest you have this kind of non-CI code in the `third_party` library as require it like this `require_once APPPATH."/third_party/Zend/barcode128.php";`

Comment: Thanks, i did the exact but still the same... Everything is ok but the bars are not showing. [https://ibb.co/bXdCL4C
https://ibb.co/YTK31tm]

Comment: are you getting any errors in CI's error log?

Comment: I'm using apache to see the log and there is no errors, nothing. I'm a noob in CI and for some reason Codeigniter is not creating any log files, all the permissions are OK.

Answer (score 0):

General suggestions (might be a problem in codeigniter):

This path is relative to the lib file in your library (or third_party) directory.

```
require('Zend/barcode128.php');
```

If you wish to require it from somewhere else is best to use predefined relative paths (BASEPATH, APPPATH, FCPATH, etc.). For example

```
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/zend/barcode128.php');
```

will look for /application/libraries/zend/barcode128.php

Also try using only first uppercase name for a lib name, like change this

```
class MyZend extends Bar128 {
```

to

```
class Myzend extends Bar128 {
```

Sometimes(tm) Codeigniter doesn't play very well with name forming for libs, helpers, etc.

A safe way to create library main files is to name them with first uppercase and rest lowercase, like for your case filename should be "Myzend.php".

As for enabling logs in codeigniter:
in config.php:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

Sets the logs to be including INFO's, may help finding the error

Comment: Thanks. Already done all that, still nothing and i change how you suggested putting lower case on Myzend... Also the log in CI still not working, i set in 1,2,3,4 and nothing, change the path and give all the permissions to teh folder, it wont generate log files... I think i have to continue the project only on PHP but i want to know why is is not working, it got me crazy

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a Myzend library or require any file. You simply need modify the bar128 class file to follow naming conventions for custom CI libraries.
A quick way to start is to rename the file using the defined prefix from your config files. Then, in its construtor, initialize the CI instance which should be used by every other method in the library.
    parent::__construct();
    $CI =& get_instance();

Then you can replace every $this with $CI in that classes.

Comment: The class should, however, be located in the library directory.